# Not able to start SpagoBI Server (All in one spagobi server) version 5.2

Tags: apache, tomcat, spagobi

**Suggest** some for loading the SpagoBI server,I tried all ways to resolve the spagobi server up. In the Catalina error is coming as -

*

> SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry
>   [com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class] from Jar
>   [jar:file:/Users.../All-In-One-SpagoBI-5.2.0/webapps/SpagoBIQbeEngine/WEB-INF/lib/icu4j-2.6.1.jar!/] for annotations
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid
>   byte tag in constant pool: 60     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:60)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2134)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2010)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1976)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1961)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1319)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1120)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1678)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

*

From google I come top know it may be JDK and tomcat version issue. I resolved that thing, but still stuck in starting the server.
I added the icu4j latest version jar, still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JDK version and Java -Version ($JAVA_HOME).
I was also facing the same issue, its because of JDK version and And JAVA_HOME mismatch.

Now am using latest JDK "jdk1.8.0_91.jdk" and set the path in JAVA_HOME.
And its working now.

Thanks,

Gupteshwari

Answer (score 0):

Here you can check

**Start SpagoBI Server**

```
cd All-In-One_SpagoBI-5.2.0/bin
./startup.sh
```

**Shutdown SpagoBI Server**

```
cd All-In-One_SpagoBI-5.2.0/bin
./shutdowm.sh
```

Hope this helps you